# Did computers render useless the teaching of approximating the Binomial with Poisson and Normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, approximation, computational-mathematics

When considering a binomial distribution with large $n$, it is (was?) usefull to use the Poisson or Normal distribution instead. One of the reason being the difficuty to compute the binomial coefficient for large $n$. Computers have since grown in performance and algorithms in efficiency.

Is it still worth teaching students about approximating $B(n;p)$ with $Po(np)$ for small values of $np$ (or small values of $n(1-p)$) and with $N(np;np(1-p))$ otherwise?

An ideal answer would include reference (personal or theoretical) to what is actually done in practice and to the applications of such approximations in undergraduate or graduate courses.

Comment: It's subjective, but I'd say there's still some use. It helps for quick estimation: for example, for reasonably large $n$, Bin(n,1/2) will usually be between somewhere in the range $n/2 \pm 3\sqrt{n}/2$, and yet it will often not be in the range $n/2 \pm \sqrt{n}/2$. Thus if you flip a coin 100 times, you should be surprised if the number of heads is less than 35 or greater than 65 but you shouldn't be surprised if the number of heads is not between 45 and 55.

Comment: (Cont.) This is good intuition for standard deviation in general. At a slightly more advanced level, it provides a good example for slow convergence in the CLT (when $p$ or $1-p$ is small), which is closely related to Poisson approximation as well. And of course there are applications where we are actually dealing with *convergence* of the binomial to the normal distribution, such as in statistical mechanics. At the computational level it would be unusual to see a problem where something like Matlab's binopdf/binocdf wouldn't be able to handle your problem, though, that much is true.

Comment: Good for the computers, but, for $X=B(n,p)$ and $n=20,000,000$ and $p=.5$ it makes no sense to compute $P(-18,727,079 \le X \le 20,874,907)$ on the computer using a summation with binomial coefficients etc. Also, one should KNOW that  for large $n$ and values of $p$ away from $0$ or $1$, the distribution of $B(n,p)$ is so close to a normal distribution as to be indistinguishable; this has many, many practical applications.

Answer (score 5):

They are indeed not so useful as calculational tools, but in terms of the theory they are important.  The approximation of binomial by Poisson motivates many applications of the Poisson distribution.  The approximation of binomial by normal leads to the Central Limit Theorem.

EDIT:
A classic example of a practical application of Poisson distribution (from von Bortkiewicz in 1898) is the number of deaths in a year in the Prussian army due to accidental horse-kicks.  We may imagine that there are a large number $n$ of Prussian soldiers, each of whom, independent of the others, has a small probability $p$ of being accidentally kicked to death by a horse in a given year.  The total number of such deaths would then be binomial with parameters $n$ and $p$.  Since $n$ is large and $p$ small, the result should be well-approximated by a Poisson distribution, and indeed this is what von Bortkiewicz found.  Actually the probability will vary from one type of soldier to another, but this does not affect the result.

Comment: Could you give some examples of the Poisson distribution applications?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon Most of them are through the concept of a Poisson process. This is a continuous time Markov chain on $\mathbb{Z}$ where all jumps are from $n$ to $n+1$. The number of jumps in a Poisson process in a time interval of length $t$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda t$. This can be approximated by the binomial distribution, by chopping up your interval into $n$ evenly sized intervals and only allowing for one event in each subinterval. Then the number of events is Binomial(n,$\lambda t/n$) which converges to Poisson($\lambda t$) as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I would mark as answered if you could justify your claim that it is indeed not useful.

Comment: The von Bortkiewicz example strikes me as a practical application of the Binomial ... I am not sure what the Poisson approximation adds to same (I suspect it adds nothing, and in fact detracts, and given a computer is thus superfluous). I do agree that, in terms of theory, it should still be taught ... but that is a separate matter.

Comment: If it's binomial we don't know $n$ and $p$ (and anyway it's not quite binomial because different soldiers have different risks), but von Bortkiewicz was able to fit a Poisson.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to show that given $\{ \{ p_{i,n} \}_{i=1}^n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n p_{i,n}=\lambda_i \in (0,\infty)$ for all $i$, and independent random variables $X_{i,n}$ distributed as Bernoulli($p_{i,n}$), then $\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,n}$ is asymptotically Poisson with some $\lambda$ which is an "average" of the $\lambda_i$. (Presumably with some further technical hypothesis like $\lambda_i$ being bounded.)

Answer (score 1):

The Central Limit Theorem, which is the topic of your question, is still of very practical use.

Most applications of $z$-tests and $t$-tests and several other hypothesis testing methods rely on the Central Limit Theorem for their validity.

Take election polling, for example. Suppose you have a voting populace of zillions of people who choose from amongst two candidates $A$ and $B$, where the the proportion of $A$ voters to $B$ voters is $p$ to $1-p$, and where $p$ is not too close to either $0$ or $1$. A pollster (in the ideal setup) randomly chooses some number of voters, say 1000 of them. This sample can be thought of as a sample taken from the distribution $B(1000,p)$. The pollster then wants to apply hypothesis testing methods, i.e. the $z$-test or $t$-test, in order to determine confidence intervals for the mean, i.e. confidence intervals for the pollsters prediction of the election outcome. What justifies applying those tests is that $B(1000,p)$ is very, very close to a normal distribution.

The same justification applies every time a medical trial samples amongst patients who do or do not respond to a medication in a proportion $p$ to $1-p$.

It also applies to a particle physics experiment when sampling particles that do or do not undergo decay in a proportion $p$ to $1-p$.

Answer (score 0):

In [Grinstead and Snell's free book](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf), Example 5.5 seems to show that the Poisson is indeed still relevant:

> Suppose that in a certain fixed amount A of blood, the average human
>   has 40 white blood cells. Let X be the random variable which gives the
>   number of white blood cells in a random sample of size A from a random
>   individual. We can think of X as binomially distributed with each
>   white blood cell in the body representing a trial. If a given white
>   blood cell turns up in the sample, then the trial corresponding to
>   that blood cell was a success. Then p should be taken as the ratio of
>   A to the total amount of blood in the individual, and n will be the
>   number of white blood cells in the individual. Of course, in practice,
>   neither of these parameters is very easy to measure accurately, but
>   presumably the number 40 is easy to measure. But for the average
>   human, we then have 40 = np, so we can think of X as being Poisson
>   distributed, with parameter λ = 40. In this case, it is easier to
>   model the situation using the Poisson distribution than the binomial
>   distribution.